# Increase performance async Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a deviceList of more than 10k items and want to send data by calling another method.

I tried to use Parallel.Foreach but I'm not sure is this the correct way to do it.

I have published this web app on Azure, I have tested this for 100 it works fine but for 10k it gets timeout issue. Is my implementation in need of any tuning?

```
private List<Task> taskEventList = new List<Task>();
public async Task ProcessStart()
{
    string messageData = "{\"name\":\"DemoData\",\"no\":\"111\"}";
    RegistryManager registryManager;

    Parallel.ForEach(deviceList, async (device) =>
    {
        // get details for each device and use key to send message
        device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(device.DeviceId);
        SendMessages(device.DeviceId, device.Key, messageData);
    });

    if (taskEventList.Count > 0)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(taskEventList);
    }
}

private void SendMessages(string deviceId, string Key, string messageData)
{
    DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(hostName, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(deviceId, deviceKey), Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt);
    //created separate Task
    var taskEvents = Task.Run(() => ProcessMessages(deviceId, string messageData));
    taskEventList.Add(taskEvents);
}

private async Task ProcessMessages(string deviceId, string messageData)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
    {
        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(messageData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code in a sensible way so we can read it

Comment: @JoePhillips updated it in  sensible way :) pls have a look

Comment: That code will not build. The messageData string needs to have double quotes escaped. Also your formatting is still kind of awkward. Some places you're intending with 2 spaces, some with 8. It's really just difficult to put energy into reading this

Comment: I got your point let me update it again

Comment: Note that `Parallel.ForEach` is not intended for async IO tasks, it's meant for CPU bound operations. To spin up parallel IO tasks use `Select` and `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: SemaphoreSlim is the throttling mechanism you will want to use here rather than Parallel.Foreach

Comment: thanks for your time can can one post it in answer with a sample code snippet , it will be helpful to me to implement :)

Comment: do you want me to use normal Foreach instead if Parallel.ForEach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's definitely a race condition, at least. `Parallel` is **only** for synchronous code, not asynchronous.

As far as I can see, you don't need `Parallel` or `Task.Run` (which are both antipatterns for ASP.NET services):

```
public async Task ProcessStart()
{
  string messageData = "{\"name\":\"DemoData\",\"no\":\"111\"}";
  RegistryManager registryManager;

  var tasks = deviceList.Select(async device =>
  {
    // get details for each device and use key to send message
    device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(device.DeviceId);
    await SendMessagesAsync(device.DeviceId, device.Key, messageData);
  }).ToList();

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task SendMessagesAsync(string deviceId, string Key, string messageData)
{
  DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(hostName, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(deviceId, deviceKey), Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt);
  await ProcessMessagesAsync(deviceId, string messageData);
}

private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(string deviceId, string messageData)
{
  var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  while (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime < TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
  {
    await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(messageData);
  }
}
```

> for 10k it got timeout issue.

15 minutes is a *long* time for an HTTP request. I think it would be worthwhile to take a step back and see if there's a better way to architect the whole system.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer , yes 15 minutes is a long time for an HTTP request but how to tackle this scenario ? I need to execute same code for 30 and 60 minutes as well :( can you help a little more in that context ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Neo One common approach is to have the HTTP request enter the work to be done in a (persistent) queue and return the ID of that work. Then there's a separate background process that processes the work in that queue. Meanwhile, the front end will poll a (different) HTTP endpoint to check the status of that ID so it knows when it's done and whether it has any errors.

Comment: so you mean to say i can use azure function in the backend which will do update operation continuous for 15 minutes....

Comment: Yes, an Azure Function is a good choice for background process.

Comment: error was related with DeviceClient only getting exception  ` {"I/O error occurred."}` i will post details another question mark this as answer.